# Technical parameters for web application?

Tags: requirements, planning, project, project-planning, quality-attributes

I'm doing a small project for the company a friend of mine works at. The project is a tool for doing [Quality function deployment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_function_deployment) using the [House of quality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Quality) method.

As part of the initial planning phase of the project, they want me to perform the same (House of Quality) method on the project, in some kind of meta way :D

I think the idea is great, but I'm struggling to come up with suitable technical parameters for the project.

So far I have the following customer requirements, with the importance in parenthesis:

- (5) Web based
- (5) Multi user
- (4) Real time (changes at one client should show up "immediately" at other clients)
- (3) Modify-and-commit mode
- (2) Trace source of customer wants (linking to surveys, etc.)

That's the "voice of the customer" part, now for the "voice of the company" ("the company" being me as a developer). These  are the technical parameters, i.e. measurable properties of the product.

I'm having a real hard time coming up with anything measurable *that is related to the customer requirements*. If I was building something physical, say a car for example, there would be stuff like `weight`, `seconds from 0-60`, `miles per gallon`, etc.

An app can't be "slightly web based" or "very web based" for example. 
`Maximum number of users` is a theoretically valid parameter, but it doesn't make much sense - if it's multi user capable, there is usually no limit of the number of users (for all practical purposes at least).

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few things that may be relevant:

- Number of clicks to achieve some common task (also hints at how intuitive the interface is)
- Size of page download (often overlooked because of faster internet)
- Time waiting to complete some common actions (waiting for database commits, etc)

You might be best of to consider what sort of UX/Usability problems you'll have in your specific application and try to measure those.